# Reflection Principle interpretation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, markov-process

Given a standard Brownian motion $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_t,\mathbb{P},(B_t)_t)$ (the standard filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_t$), we define

$$\forall t\ge 0: M_t:=\max_{0\le s\le t} B_s$$

Our professor presented to us the following Proposition with the name of *Reflection Principle*:

- $\mathbb{P}(M_t\ge a)=2\mathbb{P}(B_t\ge a)$ for all $a\ge0$, for all $t\ge 0$

I don't understand the interpretation of this result.

Comment: Which "interpretation of this result" do you fail to understand? You give none.

Answer (score 0):

The result is that the maximum of a standard Brownian motion has the same distribution as the absolute value of the Brownian motion.  The proof follows from the property that the reflected Brownian motion $M_t-B_t$ has the same properties as the Brownian motion process itself.

Comment: Our professor called $\mid B_t \mid$ reflected Brownian motion and said that $M_t-B_t$ is an equivalent process

Comment: The assertion that "the reflected Brownian motion Mt−Bt has the same properties as the Brownian motion process itself" is quite dubious. To begin with Mt−Bt is nonnegative while Bt is not.